# C# "var" argument in method without using generics (templates)

Tags: c#, templates, generics, var

I have a set of very simple function which are identical except the passed data types.  All data types are basic types.

I tried to use "var" but as expected the compiler does not know how to handle this for functions only internal types.

Do I need to use generics (templates) here?

Or is there some other built in featured to C# that I am not aware of?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Sean

```
protected bool CheckPropertyChanged(ref bool attribute, bool newValue)
{
    bool propertyChanged = false;
    if (attribute != newValue)
    {
        propertyChanged = true;
        attribute = newValue;
    }
    return propertyChanged;
}

protected bool CheckPropertyChanged(ref string attribute, string newValue)
{
    bool propertyChanged = false;
    if (attribute != newValue)
    {
        propertyChanged = true;
        attribute = newValue;
    }
    return propertyChanged;
}
```

I used the solution below but found that attribute was not being modified properly when using generics, regardless of how I called the method.  I reverted back to my original code of having separate methods for now and will revisit... I didn't take much time to investigate... it is possible I'm doing something stupid here.

```
static bool CheckPropertyChanged<T>(ref T attribute, T newValue)
{
    if (!attribute.Equals(newValue))
    {
        attribute = newValue;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what generics are for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes generics can be one solution, you can try somehting like

```
static bool CheckPropertyChanged<T>(ref T attribute, T newValue)
{
    if (!attribute.Equals(newValue))
    {
        attribute = newValue;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then call:

```
CheckPropertyChanged<bool>(ref a, b)
```

or

```
CheckPropertyChanged<string>(ref a, b)
```

or whatever type you want. Just make sure the .Equals returns what you expect depending of the types you want to compare.

I think generics is a clean solution. Is there a reason why you want to do that without generics?

Comment: I found something interesting, I could call the method without passing the generic type. i.e. "CheckPropertyChanged(ref a, b)".  I figured the compiler would complain about this.  I still have a lot to learn about C#.  Is this some type of automatic overloading that is going on here?  Where can I read more about this?

Comment: I missed your second question.  The only reason I was trying to avoid generics (which seemed to work anyway if you see my comment above) is that I am attempting to simply the code writing as much as possible for other developers, If they can literally copy base a pattern and it required very little modification, this will reduce the amount of copy paste errors.  I am making templates for any of our most common patterns in C#.  Ultimately, I would like to look into some of the ORM generators, but we need a few weeks before getting into this.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it seemed that the values I was passing by reference were not being modified correctly.  I ended up reverting to my original code.

Comment: @S.Flynn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx look for the word "Infer"